# SubSonic 3 doesn't honor schemas for update

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

I am not running Mike's latest code because it does not build and he didn't update the templates to generate code for the new Load with columns he added.  So I am one revision back in the source.

My database has tables in multiple schemas and they would not update properly.

In  SubSonic.Query Update.cs I needed to change the constructor.  I include some lines for context but I had to change line 122 to add tbl.SchemaName so that the correct DatabaseTable constructor was called and the schema name was carried through.

From this:

```
    public Update(ITable table)
    {
        _query = new SqlQuery(table.Provider);
        _provider = table.Provider;
        _query.QueryCommandType = QueryType.Update;
        ITable tbl = table;
        DatabaseTable dbTable = new DatabaseTable(tbl.Name, _provider, tbl.ClassName);
        dbTable.Columns = tbl.Columns;
        _query.FromTables.Add(dbTable);
    }
```

To this:

```
    public Update(ITable table)
    {
        _query = new SqlQuery(table.Provider);
        _provider = table.Provider;
        _query.QueryCommandType = QueryType.Update;
        ITable tbl = table;
        DatabaseTable dbTable = new DatabaseTable(tbl.SchemaName, tbl.Name, _provider, tbl.ClassName);
        dbTable.Columns = tbl.Columns;
        _query.FromTables.Add(dbTable);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a question here?  This sounds like it needs to go on SubSonic's mailing list or as an issue in SubSonic's github page: http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0